# Change skin dynamically on keyboard android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-softkeyboard

I have a black keyboard and I inflate this layout onCreateInputView()

But in my preferences, the user can change theme to white and I cannot switch the layout because when user changes the skin, the layout is already inflated...

How can I do this?

I tried with an .invalidate on inputView when keyboard was closing, but don't work

Comment: reinstantiate your activity maybe?

Comment: I have a service, but if I destroy it, then the keyboard will be slow..

Comment: when user change skin is on preference, and is static method.. I cannot call an intent..

Answer (score 0):

To change the theme, you need to restart your activity. To get an idea have a look at this: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html